# Is the medallion being used in Haunt N21?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Zombie Haunt (21) was revealed and then 2 of the players started exchanging the medallion because only the holder could make damage to the Zombie Lord. 
What I was wondering was is that possible? The trade is done for items that are not in any way used in the last turn. So if a player attacks me and he has the medallion does that count as using the medallion in any way?

The thing is that with all them gathering on the same square as the Zombie lord and each trading the item and then attempting attack they would kill the Zombie lord pretty easily if he fails 1 or 2 rolls.

As a roleplayer I always had the understanding that all happens simultaneously and that doesn't really connects with me, if everyone trade the item and everyone do the damage normally on the Zombie lord. Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: I fear you may be answering your own question here... if only the bearer of the medallion can damage the Zombie Lord, then technically you're using it. Anyone without the medallion can attack the monster, but nothing will come of it.

Comment: Well I gave both possible answers, but I wasn't sure which one was correct. Thank you for confirming my theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The errata added restrictions on this use of items:

> If there are five heroes and a monster in a room, could each of them use, say, the Spear to attack that monster, then pass it on to the next person?
>
> **No. Add this rule: "For each item, during a turn an explorer or monster that can carry items may only perform one of the following actions: use the item, give the item to another explorer, drop the item, steal the item, or pick up the item. Using the item means making any attack or roll or other action in which the item is involved in any way."**

So the heroes cannot do this, due specifically to the last sentence: "Using the item means making any attack or roll or other action in which the item is involved in any way." Even though you are not attacking with the medallion, as you would with the spear, the medallion is involved in the attack as it is a requirement for the attack to have any effect.

Comment: I seemed to remember there being a restriction that prevented the sharing, but I didn't have the time to look it up. Thanks for saving me the trouble :)

Answer (score -1):

> I fear you may be answering your own question here... if only the bearer of the medallion can damage the Zombie Lord, then technically you're using it. Anyone without the medallion can attack the monster, but nothing will come of it. - generalcrispy